# array environment: missing $ inserted and some other issues

Tags: tables, math-mode, arrays

I have the following code:

```
\begin{array}{cc|c|c|}
     & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{odd} \\
     &  & 0 & 1 \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{even} & 0 & $(+1,-1)$ & $(-1,+1)$ \\
    \cline{3-4}
     & 1 & $(-1,+1)$ & $(+1,-1)$ \\
    \cline{3-4}
\end{array}
```

It gives me a "missing $ inserted" error, and produces the following table:
[image]

As you might see, there are two issues:

1. Some of the cells are in math environment and some aren't, and it's almost the opposite of my intentions. I get that it has something to do with the error, but I can't see what's the problem or how to fix it - I simply put $...$ inside a cell that should be in math mode! Just to make it clear, I want the titles "odd", "even", "0", "1" to be regular text, and the vectors to be in math mode.
2. I don't know how to get rid of the upper parts of the three vertical lines. I want them to only strech across the two bottom cells, symmetrically to the horizontal lines.

I'd appriciate to hear your suggestions.

Comment: The `array` environment must occur in math mode. In your example, LaTeX encounters the instruction `\begin{array}{cc|c|c|}` in text mode and hence issues a complaint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two different versions using either an `array` or a `tabular` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{cc|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{odd}} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\text{even}} & 0 & (+1,-1) & (-1,+1) \\
    \cline{3-4}
     & 1 & (-1,+1) & (+1,-1) \\
    \cline{3-4}
\end{array}
\]



\begin{tabular}{cccc}
     &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{odd} \\
     & & 0 & 1 \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{even} & 0 &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\((+1,-1)\)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\((-1,+1)\)} \\
    \cline{3-4}
     & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\((-1,+1)\)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \((+1,-1)\)} \\
    \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

- `array` based approach: Place the whole array in math mode (via `\[`
  and `\]`) and use `\text` from `amsmath` for the texts.
- `tabular` based appoach: Just place the contents of each cell into
  math mode (via `\(` and `\)`).
- globally defined vertical lines: Use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` to remove
  the vertical lines where you don't want them
- locally added verticcal lines: Define your table without vertical
  lines and use `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}` or
  `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` to add them whenever needed.

Comment: +1. You might want to replace `\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &` with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &`, though.